# The screen flickers while the ubuntu logo appears

Tags: boot, graphics, intel, intel-hd

When turning on the PC while the System starts up and the Ubuntu Logo appears, then screen flickers and the system takes a long time to start up unless you touch Tab and it stops

I do not have any type of graphics card installed, only the one that comes integrated with my processor (Intel HD 520)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and an I5-6200U CPU is an HP Probook 440 G3

While the screen is flashing, the processes that are starting appear and it takes a long time

Comment: Are you getting some prompt or message telling you to press Tab? Why Tab? It's normal for the screen to flash when graphics drivers are being loaded during start-up. That doesn't seem to be a problem in the way you are describing it. Are you sure that pressing Tab is actually doing something or could this possibly be coincidence or confirmation bias?

Comment: The flickering is right when the ubuntu logo appears, and I don't think it's normal for the boot to last 5 minutes.

Comment: OK, you want more help with this-- so can you answer the fact-finding questions I asked?

Comment: If I answer them in order it would be: No, I pressed Tab by accident and it worked. Yes

Comment: Can you press Escape during startup, to see if you get any boot messages scrolling by?

Comment: If I do it gives the same effect as Tab, End the flickering